# Is anyone targeting Google Chrome yet? (Web apps, plugins)

Tags: google-chrome

Is anyone writing applications specifically to take advantage of google chrome?
Are there any enterprise users who are considering using it as the standard browser?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, I have started to pay very good attention to Google Chrome for my applications. Recent analytics show that between 6%-15% of my users are accessing my applications (varies between 6 to 15 in different applications) on Chrome. And, this number looks on an upward trend.

Thus, I can't really ignore it for testing right now.

As far as taking it as a standard goes, thats a long way off. I still have to test for IE6! :( Though, we have been planning to start using features like Gears (inbuilt in Chrome - downloadable elsewhere) once Chrome crosses the 25% mark. Thats when I believe that we will be looking at Chrome to be our preferred browser. I hope that we have Chrome 1.0+ by then! ;)

Comment: If it's any consolation, you can use IE8.js to have IE5+ to act like IE8 :D (or IE7.js to have IE5+ to act like IE7).

http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 3):

I switched to Chrome and haven't looked back except for the occasional site which doesn't work properly, forcing me to load it in Firefox. All my existing web applications work fine on it, and I'm using it for primary testing on my current development project.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not actually targeting chrome, but I have added chrome to my browsers to test sites on.  I've found some odd quirks in this product where some plugins cause the browser to hang, or run really slow in some environments, but they are still in beta in active development.  But I definately now make sure sites I work on render well in chrome, as well as firefox, latest versions of IE, safari, Konquerer and opera.  I usually check out how it looks on lynx as well, that helps me catch "un-alternated text" in images.  Yeah, I know that isn't a word, but some people will understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

Because chrome uses the webkit to render HTML, you can be assured if it works in safari, it'll work under chrome, however it's rendering engine [isn't up to scratch](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kurafire/2822606444/) quite yet. I think writing applications that take advantage of it is similar to writing iPhone applications, remember chrome is expected to be adopted by android to make it similar to iPhone. That way it pretty much takes advantage of all those iPhone apps.

Would I install it as the browser of choice? not yet - but i'll certainly work on valid web pages that will render across all browsers.

Comment: If you use JavaScript you don't have that guarantee because it uses a different JS VM. My web app had some JS issues in Chrome it didn't have in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

One of our major customers has outlawed Chrome because it installs on the C drive without asking.  They deploy a standard image with a small C drive and large D drive so they can easily re-clone the system part of the image on C without destroying the client's personal files on D.  Most software allows you to choose the install directory.  Anything that violates this is disallowed, and they're a big enough company to have some weight with most vendors.

Answer (score 1):

We have enough headaches trying to support

- Firefox
- Two versions of IE which have their own iffy bugs
- Safari

I'm not sure why we continue to support Safari. Most of our users (corporate) use IE6 or IE7. We try to make sure that things work in both of those.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not for programming purposes but Chrome w/ Google Reader makes for the most powerful RSS reader. Can handle up to 1500 feeds w/ performance still ok, managing subscriptions still functioning.

Comment: I just learned about RSS Cloud and River2 this week. I think River2 may have some potential but still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it on my work machine, but that's about it. It's been stable for me, and I like the barebones UI. I'll still switch to Firefox for the web developer extensions however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm liking some of GoogleChrome- the Start page with your 9 most recent is the winner for me. The interface takes a little getting used to, but the speed is impressive, especially with Gmail.

However, it glitches with Java, which rules it out for serious work at the moment. I use FireFox mostly and have Chrome for the "other" websites at work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering using GWT on an intranet project and considering suggesting to the users that use Chrome to take advantage of the enhanced Javascript performance. Any AJAX-heavy app would be a great candidate to target Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

At my company, we're not targeting it, but we're definitely paying attention to it. My boss is using it as his primary browser, and I have implemented browser detection for it in our scripts in case we ever to need to target it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has the .png opacity bug where the transparent parts of the .png are a solid color if you try to transition the opacity from 0 to 1.  In IE7 the opaque parts are black, and in Chrome, they are white.  Today, I decided to go ahead and account for this bug in my JavaScript.  I don't really test sites on Chrome that often, but I am actually using it for almost all of my browsing.

Answer (score 0):

I will target Chrome as soon as a stable Linux and OSX client is available.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting Chrome/Chromium right now, I think is like targeting Konqueror web browser. It will get popular, but you should wait to a more stable beta, and/or some Linux and OS X client.

Answer (score 0):

My website statistics shows 3.xx % visitors using Chrome which arrived just few weeks back. And Opera is only 4.xx % which has been around for several years.

Easily you can see that rate at which Chrome is picking up.

You can see how easily Google takes over all areas of your computing world and personal world too.

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome uses Webkit, it has the same rendering engine and DOM support as Safari (not necessarily the same revision of Webkit though). By testing in Safari, you can generally get by without worrying about Chrome. Any differences you find are probably just bugs that you should file on instead of work around.

However, because Chrome uses a different JS engine, there may be a few incompatibilities with Safari. So, if you're doing anything with JS, you might as well fire up Chrome and see if there's anything obviously wrong.

Generally though, you don't target browsers, you target rendering engines (with their associated DOM support and JS engines).

Answer (score -1):

I am using Google Chrome, so far all the web apps I have work fine in it with no modifications.

Answer (score -2):

No.

1. Why help Google further build an evil empire? In this particular case it is so obvious that they do not care about users but only obsessed with gathering usage info.
2. It's not any major player yet

Comment: 1) Chrome doesn't actively gather any information from the user. It's up to the websites to do that, which makes Chrome no worse than other browsers

2) It matches Opera in Market share (~3.5% at the moment), so while not one of the top two it still has a lot of users.

It's a shame that people's paranoia of Google prevents them from using many of their (very good, IMHO) products.

Comment: "Chrome doesn't actively gather any information from the user."  I don't know what you mean by that. Read the EULA.